# Newton interpolation in python using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to use matplotlib to draw a picture of Newton interpolation, but I met with some difficulties. My figure don't through the last some points. Can you help me? If my code is wrong, please tell me the details, thank you.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def coef(x, y):
    '''x : array of data points
       y : array of f(x)  '''
    x.astype(float)
    y.astype(float)
    n = len(x)
    a = []
    for i in range(n):
        a.append(y[i])

    for j in range(1, n):

        for i in range(n - 1, j - 1, -1):
            a[i] = float(a[i] - a[i - 1]) / float(x[i] - x[i - j])

    return np.array(a)  # return an array of coefficient


def Eval(a, x, r):
    ''' a : array returned by function coef()
       x : array of data points
       r : the node to interpolate at  '''
    x.astype(float)
    n = len(a) - 1
    temp = a[n]
    for i in range(n - 1, -1, -1):
        temp = temp * (r - x[i]) + a[i]
    return temp  # return the y_value interpolation


if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = np.linspace(0, 20, 11)
    y = np.random.randint(0, 10, 11)
    # y = np.asarray([i ** 2 for i in x])

    a = coef(x, y)
    tmp_x = np.linspace(0, 21, 21)
    tmp_y = [Eval(a, tmp_x, i) for i in tmp_x]

    plt.plot(x, y, linestyle='', marker='o', color='b')
    plt.plot(tmp_x, tmp_y, linestyle='--', color='r')
    plt.show()
```

[picture of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBKIG.png)

Answer (score 0):

OK， I had solve my problem after reading some paper about Newton Interprolation. But the comments are written in Chinese， when I have time, I will translate it into Engilsh.
[image of Newton Interpolation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IR920.png)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


class Newton(object):
def __init__(self, x, y):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y

def run(self, tmp_x):
    # 构造差商表
    table = np.zeros([len(self.x), len(self.x) + 1], dtype=float)

    for i in range(len(self.x)):  # 将x 和 y 放入 差商表的前两列
        table[i][0] = self.x[i]
        table[i][1] = self.y[i]
    # 计算差商
    for i in range(2, table.shape[1]):  # i is 2 to 5
        for j in range(i - 1, table.shape[0]):  # j is
            table[j][i] = (table[j][i - 1] - table[j - 1][i - 1]) / (self.x[j] - self.x[j - i + 1])

    # print(table)  # 输出差商表
    # for i in range(table.shape[0]):
    #     for j in range(table.shape[1]):
    #         print(table[i][j], end=' ')
    #     print('\n')
    # print('\n\n')

    # 由牛顿插值函数求给出的x序列对应的y序列
    tmp_y = []
    for ans_x in tmp_x:  # 遍历每个x
        ans_y = 0  # 对应于输入序列每个x的相应y值
        for i in range(table.shape[0]):
            tmp = table[i][i + 1]  # 求值多项式第 i 项， tab[i][i + 1]为其系数
            for j in range(i):
                tmp *= (ans_x - self.x[j])
            ans_y += tmp
        tmp_y.append(ans_y)
    return tmp_y


if __name__ == '__main__':
    plt.rcParams['font.sans-serif'] = ['SimHei']
    plt.rcParams['axes.unicode_minus'] = False

    sr_x = np.linspace(0, 20, 11)
    sr_fx = np.random.randint(0, 20, 11)

    tmp_x = np.linspace(0, 20)

    demo = Newton(sr_x, sr_fx)
    tmp_y = demo.run(tmp_x)

    print(tmp_x)
    print(tmp_y)

    plt.plot(sr_x, sr_fx, 'ro', label='插值节点')
    plt.plot(tmp_x, tmp_y, label='牛顿插值')
    enter code here
    plt.xlabel('x')
    plt.ylabel('y')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```